# onchange event not appearing in rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my Application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title>SpreemoCodetest</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<script>
    function findDocs() {
    $.get("/appointments/list_doctors");
    }
</script>
</head>
```

I have this collection_select in a partial

```
<%= collection_select(:appointment, :ailment, AilmentsSpecialties.all, :id, :ailment, :prompt => 'select an ailment', html_options: {:onChange => "findDocs();"})%>
```

The partial appears the select tag appears I do not see my onchange function in my rendered html.

Comment: Do you see any error in browser devtool? if so what is that? FYI, in Rails we have much better place to put those JS, which is app/assets/javascript, and use this place to organize your JS code..

Comment: I checked the Chrome Developer Tools console and I saw no errors.  I also (just for laughs) checked the rails log and saw no errors.  I can put the js script into app/assets/javascript.  (That's probably a good idea anyway.)  I just don't think it will make a difference.  

I can see the script when I view the page source.  I see no errors.

Comment: Well, in `app/assets/javascript` you will write the code other way. Like `$('#someId').on('change', function() { //here out your own code })`. @user. Ofcourse remove `{ :onChange => "findDocs();" }`..

Comment: So I wouldn't have to add the onchange directly on the select itself?

Comment: Do the way I said, not like the way you are trying to do. Your attempt may work, but I never wrote JS to execute like the way you are doing. I found others to do that way though in PhP.

Comment: Also I think it is [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) not `onChange`, right?

Comment: Arup Rakshit, I'm not clear about what you mean.  Can you please clarify? 
It sounds like you're telling me to:   

1) remove the on change in the collection_select.
2) create a jQuery function e.g. $(#id_of_collection_select).on('change',function(){//my code here}

Is what I said correct?  I just want to clarify.  Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<%= collection_select(:appointment, :ailment, AilmentsSpecialties.all, :id, :ailment, { :prompt => 'select an ailment' }, { :onChange => "findDocs();" })%>
```